# React.js: How can I render a single component from an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components

I have an array full of components called "componentPack". I'm trying to figure out how to render a certain component based on its index in the array.The part that is giving me trouble is rendering the component in JSX. To solve the problem I am using an intermediate array called "stager" that I push one component to and then map from:

```
var comp = stager.map((Component) => {
  return <Component />;
});
```

Is there anyway to pick a component directly from the original array?

Something like:

```
var comp = () => {return <{componentPack[3][2]} />;}
```

I feel as tho I do not really understand how JSX works in this case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can just opt for conditional rendering from the map component like

```
var index = 3;
const component = componentPack.map((Component, idx) => {
    if(idx === index) {
         return <Component/>
    } else {
         return null;
    }
})
```

then your can just render it like

```
render() {
    return (<div>{component}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the jsx object directly. For example if you componentPack is an array of components like so:

```
const componentPack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((item) =>
  <Component/>
);
```

You can reference any individual element and get the specific component like:

```
render(){
  return componentPack[2] //Will return the third Component
}
```